# shared_ptr release

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to release pointer from boost::shared_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525764/how-to-release-pointer-from-boostshared-ptr)
>   [Detach a pointer from a shared_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833356/detach-a-pointer-from-a-shared-ptr)

I'm attempting to release a shared_ptr (the way you can release a unique_ptr). I know this doesn't make sense when the shared_ptr isn't unique, but I have a shared_ptr which is guaranteed to be unique. I've tried...

```
m_pObj.reset((T*)nullptr, [](T* const){});
```

...but it just deletes the object anyway. I'm not sure what that deleter argument is good for if shared_ptr winds up calling delete anyway.

Is there any way to achieve this (solutions specific to VS2010 are welcome if there is no other way).

Comment: Why do you want to subvert `shared_ptr`?

Comment: The deleter accompanies _the NEW value_

Comment: The only way to release it is probably to give someone else a shared_ptr, or rethink your entire design

Answer (score 5):

<sup>Before this get's closed as dup, I'll add my take on this.</sup>

*I think* there are a lot of good reasons why you would *occasionally* want to release a shared_ptr (or boost::scoped_ptr). However, the people who designed these classes think that you should not be able to do this. (It's their baby, they have a right to.)

As far as I can see, it is simply not possible to detach a shared_ptr. You will need to either use another class or come up with a design where you do not need to detach it.

And I should [read the dupes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833356/detach-a-pointer-from-a-shared-ptr/5995770#5995770) as you *can* actually hack it together using a very special deleter.

Comment: I actually just solved this after reading this....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833356/detach-a-pointer-from-a-shared-ptr/5995770#5995770