# Extracting a raw pointer from a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, tr1

Is it possible to extract a raw pointer from a `std::shared_ptr` or `std::tr1::shared_ptr` object? The intent is to tell the smart pointer object that I don't want it to manage the lifetime of the object anymore. The context is that I have an API that takes a raw pointer from users and does some processing on the object. To make things easier to manage API creates a `shared_ptr` out of this raw pointer. Now, the user might ask for the object to be returned. In that case, when giving the processed object back to the user I want to give back the raw pointer. However, I have not found a way to do that. Using `.get()` is not possible as then the smart pointer will have to be kept alive indefinitely. I would have given back a `unique_ptr` but that is not available in `tr1`.

Basically I want to move the raw pointer out of the shared_ptr.

Comment: Could you make an example with code? I don't quite understand why you would want to return a pointer to the user.

Comment: Is the pointer to a class you have control over, or derived from a class you have control over?

Comment: @Jefffrey , unfortunately, a code sample would be too complicated. Just realizing how difficult it is to explain, I am beginning to think I need to change my design :)

Comment: @341008, yeah, it looks like you should. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are searching for the method `release()` of `shared_ptr`. Sorry - there is no such method by design.

Here I found a funny way to do what you want - https://stackoverflow.com/a/13701773/233885.

You should think about using `shared_ptr` again in you context (ownership).

Comment: Yup, I was looking for a `release()` method. The answer suggested in that post is probably too risky for a non-expert like me. I don't want to have to track down bugs in that :). I think I will have to rethink my design. Thanks anyway.