# How do I pass protobuf's boost::shared_ptr pointer to function?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, rapidjson, make-shared

I have to pass a `boost::shared_ptr`:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Protobuf::Person::Profile> pProfile =
      boost::make_shared<Protobuf::Person::Profile>();
```

which is protobuf's pointer, to a protobuf's function `oPerson.set_allocated_profile(pProfile)` but `oPerson.set_allocated()` expects a pointer to `Protobuf::Person::Profile`.

I have tried couple of ways but I think when I try to convert protobuf object to JSON using `pbjson::pb2Json` which is a library function built on rapid json, the pointer goes out of scope causing segmentation fault.

**Method 1:**

```
oPerson.set_allocated_profile(pProfile.get());
```

**Method 2:**

```
oPerson.set_allocated_profile(&*pProfile);
```

Comment: Hard to help without more context: review your scopes of lifetime and make sure the memory is still valid when it gets used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method 1 and 2 are equivalent since Protobuf messages don't overload `operator&`.

Protobuf manages lifetimes (and I think Copy-On-Write semantics) internally, so I'd favour value semantics throughout.

I'm never exactly sure whether (and how) ownership is transferred with the allocated setters (`set_allocated_*`). If you find a source that documents it, please tell me!

**Iff** `set_allocated_profile` takes ownership of the pointer, then neither of your approaches is correct. You'd need to release the pointer from your owning shared pointer (see [How to release pointer from boost::shared_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525764/how-to-release-pointer-from-boostshared-ptr/1526450#1526450)).

**Iff** `set_allocated_profile` does *not* take ownership, I'd prefer to write:

```
oPerson.mutable_profile()->CopyFrom(*pProfile);
```

Or equivalently:

```
*oPerson.mutable_profile() = *pProfile;
```