# Extending/Incrementing the ref count of a smart pointer

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, ownership-semantics

Suppose I have a method that defines a `shared_ptr`. After the method finishes, the `shared_ptr` will also be deleted. In the interim I have another member that uses that `shared_ptr`. So I would like to extend the lifetime of the `shared_ptr` past the initial method.

```
void initial_method(int input)
{
  std::shared_ptr<int> a { std::make_shared<int>(input) };
  some_delayed_method(a);
}
```

Is it possible to manually increase the reference count of a by one in this example?

**`some_delayed_method()` is like a detachment and is referring to `a` at a time after the `initial_method()` has returned.**

Comment: You don't have to do this. The `std::shared_ptr` is valid for the duration of the method call.

Comment: Simply making a copy of the shared_ptr should be sufficient to extend the lifetime of the `int` it is pointing to, is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify what the problem is: I see that at least two people (myself included) misunderstood it. Maybe show more of your code. Maybe add some print-statements which show where the problem is.

Comment: @OS2 You editted your question which completely changes its scope! In any case, you should show the code for the some_delay_method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to release pointer from boost::shared\_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525764/how-to-release-pointer-from-boostshared-ptr)

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't call `some_delayed_method` without a `shared_ptr` to the object and *any* `shared_ptr` to the object extends its lifetime, there is nothing you need to do.

Comment: @OS2 I read it again and stand by this answer. Whatever code calls `some_delayed_method`, whenever and however it calls it, must hold  `std::shared_ptr` to `a` which keeps it around already.

Answer (score -1):

If `some_delayed_method` saves the pointer in some external data structure, and this pointer will later be used, you should use `shared_ptr` for that.

```
class X
{
public:
    void initial_method(int input)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<int> a { std::make_shared<int>(input) };
        some_delayed_method(a);
    }

    void some_delayed_method(const std::shared_ptr<int>& a)
    {
        use_later = a;
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<int> use_later;
}
```

This way, the reference count will be handled automatically.

---

You may insist on using a raw pointer to save the data for later:

```
void some_delayed_method(const std::shared_ptr<int>& a)
{
    use_later = a.get();
}

...

int* use_later;
```

This is not a proper way to save the data. To make it work (or appear to work), you have to do some hack. For example, make another reference to the data, and leak it:

```
void some_delayed_method(const std::shared_ptr<int>& a)
{
    use_later = a.get();
    new std::shared_ptr<int>(a); // horrible hack; please never do it! but it works...
}
```

This hack leaks the allocated `std::shared_ptr` so it can never be deleted, thus its refcount is not decremented and the allocated `int` is leaked.

Comment: The "hack" indeed leaks the `new`ly allocated `std::shared_ptr` so it can never be `delete`d, thus the refcount of the allocated `int` is not decremented and it is leaked, too.

Comment: Thanks for the description of how it works! I forgot to mention that the `int` object itself is leaked.

Comment: OK thanks. I was looking for a way to not have to make a second copy. At this rate, I might as well just use a raw pointer (new delete) instead.

Comment: This `use_later = a;` has be carried out before the call to `some_delayed_method()`. I might as well use a raw pointer.

Comment: Why are you suggesting to deliberately leak memory... with a smart pointer of all things?

Comment: @OS2 Don't forget that you have the option of using `shared_ptr` to store the additional reference, as I described in the first part of my answer. This is the proper solution, without hacks.

Comment: @anatolyg Your second point isn't even obvious so IDK why you'd bring it up. The question remains unanswered.